# Get Global Stats CSGO via steam web api

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I saw GetGlobalStatsForGame WEBAPI in

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

I want some global stats 
for CSGO but i dont know the param NAME
Can any one tell me what's the param for name[0] or where I can get the name list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you looking for the  name argument is the name of the stat you want to retrieve.

For example if you want to retrieve the "Total Galil AR Kills" you would do something like this:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalStatsForGame/v0001/?format=json&appid=730&count=1&name[0]=total_shots_galilar
```

However, I do not think CSGO aggregates "global" stats. For a single game you can go to the site *SteamDB* and check the stats pages:

```
https://steamdb.info/app/730/stats/
```

Cheers

Daniel